# How to shutdown a rpc server in golang?

Tags: go

```
var listener net.Listener
if listener, err = net.Listen("tcp",address); err != nil {
    return 
}
server = rpc.NewServer()
server.Register(new(TunnelRPC))

go server.Accept(listener)
```

I started a rpc server using the code above.  Since I want to shut it down, I tried

```
listener.close()
```

But it does not work, the err is `use of closed network connection`

How to shutdown this rpc server?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Te6rLFa1bZM this is similar to my question.

Comment: @Kousik Are you sure there is an API named Shutdown()? I am using go 1.13 and I could not find one.

Comment: I was looking into some othe package. sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Wait for termination signal
    interruptSignal := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interruptSignal, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-interruptSignal

    // Terminate the server
    server.GracefulStop()
    listener.Close()
```

Comment: This is a good answer. And I found that I do not need to shutdown the server. Rejecting requests is all what I want.